# How to count the number of rows in a list? SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm currently a beginner in swiftUI and I just wanted to know how to calculate the number of rows in a list. For example: Lets say my list has x rows:

```
List {
   Text("row1")
   Text("row2")
   Text("row3")
      //and so on....

 }
```

How would I find how many rows are there? I've tried researching this, but I just come across more harder and complex code.

Comment: you already answered that in your question. your list has x rows. But seriously, why do you need to know that?

Comment: I think the answer is you can't. The reason is that this is a declarative syntax, so it expects you already know how many rows you have put in. It's a different way of thinking, to be sure. It's more like HTML than traditional code.

Comment: @user3441734 I think I meant that I wanted to figure out what "x" was. Like for example maybe 3 or 4 or 100.

Comment: why do you need to know that? really, try to answer. do you really need to know that?

Comment: Perhaps you're trying to do something that would require us to know what it is so we can think of a suitable approach here. So try to explain what you want to do with the info about what *x* is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the x Text elements in your example you could use an array with a state wrapper:

```
struct ExampleView: View {

@State var rowElements: [String] = ["row1", "row2", "row3"]

var body: some View {
    List(rowElements, id: \.self) {rowElement in
        Text(rowElement)
    }
}
```

When you now add/remove Elements from the array your List automatically updates. That means the number of List rows equals the number of Strings contained in `rowElements` and can be read with `rowElements.count()`

Answer (score 0):

This will help both of you to do it way easier without having to hard code or even create that array.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Example: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0 ..< 5) { item in
            DetailExampleView(count: item)
        }
    }
}

struct Example_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Example()
    }
}

struct DetailExampleView: View {
    @State var count: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        Text("Item no.\(count)")
    }
}
```

Anyway, if you would like your count to start on 1 instead of 0, just add

```
DetailExampleView(count: item + 1)
```